# TcpListener проблема принятия данных

Tags: c#

Проблема с передачей данных через BinaryReader/BinaryWriter.

Если я захочу передать файл от сервера до клиента в локальной сети, я его спокойно получу. Если же я его попробую получить из-вне, мне выкинет тайм-аут т.к binaryReader.ReadString() не смогла прочитаться.

Проблема заключается в следующем. Если отправить файл объемом в 10кб а следом файл в 50кб, то этого не возникнет. У меня вопрос, это можно исправить? Пробовал изменять буферы и клиента и сервера, не помогло. Вот код:

Клиент:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("..."), 80);

        NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
        BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(networkStream);
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);
        binaryWriter.Write("GetFile");
        binaryWriter.Flush();
        if (binaryReader.ReadString() == "TakeFile") // If I try to load a file from outside, it stays on that line. After about 10 seconds, displays an error about TimeOut
        {
            int Lenght = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
            byte[] file = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Lenght);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Сервер:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpServer server = new HttpServer(new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80));
    server.Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}

public class HttpServer
{
TcpListener listener;

public HttpServer(TcpListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void Start()
{
    listener.Start();
    WaitRequest();
}

private void WaitRequest()
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
                BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(networkStream);
                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);


                byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("...");

                if (binaryReader.ReadString() == "GetFile")
                {
                    binaryWriter.Write("TakeFile");
                    binaryWriter.Write(file.Length);
                    binaryWriter.Write(file); // But if we remove or change the bytes of the file to something else, the client will accept it absolutely normal.
                    binaryWriter.Flush();
                }

                client.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    })
    {
        IsBackground = true
    }.Start();
}
}
```

Ошибка:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удален
>   ный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение. ---> System.Net.Socket
>   s.SocketException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключени
>   е
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size,
>    SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 s
>   ize)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 s
>   ize)
>      at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
>      at ConsoleApp1.Program.Connect()

Comment: Мне хоть кто нибудь может помочь?)

Comment: Так у вас проблема с ReadString(). Никогда им не пользовался, но напсано "The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time., то есть похоже строке должна предшествовать закодированная длина этой самой строки. И вы должны отправить длину строки похоже через BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt перед отправкой самой строки

Answer (score 0):

На клиенте пробовали играться с networkStream.ReadTimeout?

[NetworkStream.Flush ничего не делает, зарезервирован на будущее](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush?view=netframework-4.8)

Лучший вариант это передавать сначала какой объем данных будет передан, а потом передавать данные, клиент после получения объема, ждет пока не придут все данные.

В итоге выяснили что дело не в программе, данные до клиента запущенного на моем компе доходят нормально.

Comment: Честно говоря нет, но когда тайм-аут выкидывает вместе с ошибкой, проходит около 15-и секунд. Я думаю 100кб за 15 секунд можно было спокойно отправить и принять. На счет объема, каким образом я должен это сделать?

Comment: Так-же пробовал играться с общим тайм-аутом и буферами на TcpClient и на TcpListener`e
Не помогло. 

Я не так давно выяснил 1 вещь. Если сразу кинуть файл поменьше а затем закрыть сервер клиент и опять открыть но уже с большим файлом - всё передается но потом что-то происходит и опять не передается. Не понимаю честно говоря в чем проблема, может мне нужно делать какие-то манипуляции с памятью?

Comment: А напишите какую именно ошибку выкидывало, у меня повторить на локальной машине ошибку не удалось, единственное какую ошибку кидало, если на клиенте ReadTimeout сделать 500 к примеру, а на сервере слип поставить 1000, тогда клиент отваливался с ошибкой System.IO.IOException Не удается прочитать данные из траспортного соединения: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной ..
если ReadTimeout оставить по умолчанию, и использовать слипы между записью в стрим на стороне сервера, то все ок, клиент спокойно дожидается ответа, т.е. пока канал стабилен все нормально отсылается и принимается

Comment: Изменил вопрос, туда добавил ошибку. С этим я уже парюсь, нуу... Неделю где-то. Если вы мне поможете, я буду очень благодарен этому. В церковь сходить могу.

Comment: А вы пробовали заменить текстовые команды на код команды(байт), к примеру "GetFile" - отсылать 10, "TakeFile" - 20, останутся ли при этом ошибки?

Comment: Не-а, так или иначе мне нужно отдавать string. TakeFile и GetFile это просто проверочное слово. Если получиться решить проблему, то в string Будет информация от кого куда и зачем летит файл а так-же его названия. 

Ну к примеру если мы сделаем так. Читать придется что-то вроде BinaryReader.ReadByte()?

Comment: Я могу включить для вас сервер на своем компьютере, а вы с помощью клиента можете кидать коннект. Если вы заинтересованы разобраться в этом и помочь мне, можем начать переписку в том же дискорде, и что нибудь пробовать вместе. Но это уже если вы хотите..

Comment: Я отправил запрос с Ogyvan n1#4645.